# Typo on 'Edit Tag Wikis' Privilege Description Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, spelling

The Privilege description for "Edit Tag Wikis" has a typo on both StackOverflow and MetaStackOverflow (did not check other StackExchange sites).

The second heading, "When should edit a tag wiki?" should likely read "When should **I** edit a tag wiki?"

This is related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67329/bug-small-typo-on-privileges-edit-tag-wiki/67345#67345 which seems to have regressed somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on sorting this out. This is actually caused by 2 things:

1. I have to manually sync the privilege wikis on meta to the local repo on a regular basis, till they are stable.
2. There is a really nasty serialization bug with the persistence of privileges in our cache. This is causing much confusion. The reference to the original post is not being serialized, so its lost as soon as we go to the cache. Which causes it to default.

**edit**

I wrote a tiny tool to sync all the sites up, just ran it, and will try to remember to run it weekly (at least)

I also deployed a fix for the serialization stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is something deeper going on with the system.

The [latest revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66738/revisions) of the wiki in question *does* contain the typo fix, but it's not being displayed on the page.

If I try to edit then save the latest revision, I get an "Oops, something bad happened" error page. I'm guessing this is due to the recent server migrations.